# Realm Android aggregating on child object

Tags: android, database, realm, realm-mobile-platform

```
public class ChallengeDB extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int challengeId;


    private String targetType;
    private RealmList<ChallengeTargetDB> ChallengeTargetDB;
    private boolean isTargetPerParticipant;
}



  public class ChallengeTargetDB extends RealmObject {
        @PrimaryKey
        private int targetId;
        private String targetName;
        private String description;
        private long targetValue;
        private int targetStep;
        private boolean isPassed;
}
```

I have these 2 tables linked as following and I need to get max "targetValue" value of a specific challengeId.

The query for which I have written is as follows

```
RealmResults<ChallengeDB> challengeDBs = realm.where(ChallengeDB.class)
                    .equalTo(WorkoutCashConstants.COLUMN_CHALLENGE_ID, challengeDB.getChallengeId()).findAll();

            long max = challengeDBs.max("ChallengeTargetDB.targetValue").longValue();
```

I get up ending exception as follows

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Aggregates on child object fields are not supported: ChallengeTargetDB.targetValue
```

Answer (score 1):

With Realm 3.5.0+

```
public class ChallengeTargetDB extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int targetId;
    private String targetName;
    private String description;
    private long targetValue;
    private int targetStep;
    private boolean isPassed;

    @LinkingObjects("ChallengeTargetDb")
    private final RealmResults<ChallengeDb> targetOfChallenge = null;
  }
```

Then

```
 RealmResults<ChallengeTargetDB> challengeDBs = realm.where(ChallengeTargetDB.class)
                .equalTo("targetOfChallenge." + WorkoutCashConstants.COLUMN_CHALLENGE_ID, challengeDB.getChallengeId()).findAll();

        long max = challengeDBs.max("targetValue").longValue();
```

Comment: do I need to provide migration of linking objects as well if so how ??

Comment: @LinkingObjects shouldn't cause migration, because they aren't *actually* part of the schema.

Comment: Sorry to get back to you so late was working on something else. Up the version of the realm and linking objects work just fine. Thanks a bunch for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, aggregates on linked object's field are not supported. You need to compute it by yourself.

Try this:

```
Number max = null;
for (ChallengeDB item : challengeDBs) {
    if (max == null) {
        max = item.ChallengeTargetDB.max();
    } else {
        Number tmp = item.ChallengeTargetDB.max();
        max = max.longValue() > tmp.longValue() ? max : tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already obtained max value using a similar method. But my query is can this be a feature request??